# Multiline match on preceding text in Sublime keymap

Tags: sublimetext3

I have the following command in my `sublime-keymap`:

```
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": { "contents": "${1:key}: ${0:'value'}" },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.js" },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{\\s*$" },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "\\)\\s*\\{\\s*$" }
    ]
},
```

This matches the following text just fine (pipe = insertion point):

```
{ |
```

…but not this:

```
{
   |
```

…because `preceding_text` only seems to include the preceding text on the same line. Is there any way to match on more than one line here?